# SonarJS not respecting sonar.javascript.globals

Tags: sonarqube, sonarjs

I have configured a long list of `sonar.javascript.globals` on the server side (SonarQube) for all js projects, however when triggering a sonar check from CI with sonar-maven-plugin I get the known `S3827 (ReferenceErrorCheck)`. When I extend the mvn command to include `Dsonar.javascript.globals=CustomFunc`, this CustomFunc is respected as known.

Is there a way to fix this or I have misunderstood the usage of the global setting? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you exactly do?

Comment: First, thanks @omikey for the edit. @louis-suggy I run sonar checks on js projects and have defined a list of sonar.javascript.globals under General Settings, however those seem to be ignored and I have to explicitly provide the variables and functions for the sonar-maven-plugin as: `mvn sonar:sonar -Psonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://host  -Dsonar.branch=master -Dsonar.report.export.pat -Dsonar.javascript.globals=Server`, otherwise the quality gate fails with ReferenceErrorCheck. Is that more clear?

Comment: Can you post debug log of your analysis (output of `sonar-scanner -X`? Are you sure you are not overriding your global settings in your `sonar-project.properties`?